# Boostrap 4 and datepicker dropdown position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 (final) with the [boostrap-datepicker-plugin 1.7.1](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) 
Since Bootstrap 4 no longer uses .input-group-addon elements (for calendar icon) but .input-group-prepend and .input-group-append I modified the plugin code in this way

```
//this.component = this.element.hasClass('date') ? this.element.find('.add-on, .input-group-addon, .btn') : false;

this.component = this.element.hasClass('date') ? this.element.find('.input-group-prepend, .input-group-append, .btn') : false;
```

In this way the plugin seems to work well with the new input-group elements, but unfortunately if I add css margin to the container that contains the input of the datepicker, the dropdown-menu is shown in the wrong position.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dex01/phh6uxy7/5/)

I tried to find the solution to this problem, but without success.
Someone can help me to fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have a container with `position: relative` to let the plugin calculate the position correctly.

In your case the [default container](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#container) is the `body`, so you can either set

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

**or better**, define a different container in datepicker initialization:

```
$( ".date" ).datepicker({
  container: '.container',
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

then set position relative to the `.container` class

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

[FIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/phh6uxy7/9/)

Comment: It's perfect! Thank YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Add a container in your javascript:

```
  $( ".date" ).datepicker({
container: '.datepicker_wrapper'
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

this makes the datepicker to be added as child of the .datepicker_wrapper in your html DOM, rather then being added at the bottom of your body. This way you can easily position it the way you want with position relative on the wrapper and absolute on the picker itself.

here the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mh8h7jfe/2/

EDIT: updated the fiddle to differ between the 2 datepicker.

```
    $( ".datepicker_wrapper" ).datepicker({
container: '.datepicker_wrapper',
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
$( ".datepicker_wrapper2" ).datepicker({
container: '.datepicker_wrapper',
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

And css:

```
.datepicker_wrapper, .datepicker_wrapper2{
position:relative;
}
```

I now put in the html "datepicker_wrapper" and "datepicker_wrapper2" and call those 2 classes in JS aswell as using those classes as container.

This works fine for me

Comment: Unfortunately your example does not work as it should.

Comment: what? why? for me the datepicker opens perfectly below the input in the fiddle? can you explain what is not working? or whats wrong with the fiddle? you might forgot the ".datepicker_wrapper{position:relative;}" in your CSS?

Comment: With firefox and chrome (in your fiddle) if i click on the first (input-group-append) the dropdown shown on second datapicker input.. Moreover if I click directly on the input field the dropdown remains open. But does it work well for you ???

Comment: Updated my fiddle and explained it. your were right, I didn´t differ the 2 inputs and both had the same class, so this bug occured. For me this one works fine

Comment: Now is ok, but @pumpkinzzz solution is more clean. Thanks

Comment: its actually exactly the same, I even think my solution is more reliable since I seperate the 2 inputs in its classes, so there can´t be issues with selecting the right one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just include a button tag in the markup with "btn" in the class so you don't have to change the source code but it may not fix your margin issue.

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```